# Anaconda / Spyder4.1.1

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I had to update my spyder to version 4.1.1 so I updated Spyder to that specific version.
After updating and rebooting the spyder in my anaconda navigator would not start
Then I opened anaconda promopt and typed the commander spyder --reset which resetted

Then it wouldnt restart without an enormous page long of error. I rebooted my computer again.
Now I can open Spyder 4.1.1. but my import matplotlib as plt command won't import the desired library.

I checked in my current enviroment whether the matplotlib was present (It was gone for some odd reason). so I tried installing that package using the navigator (Tab "Enviroments" and then looking for it with the fuzzy search )
[image]

When I hit install, I can see in the bottom of the navigator that it is "installing" but then I get an error message stating: Multiple Errors Encountered

When I press "Learn more" it directs me to another website
I am very lost at the moment, it shouldnt be that hard to update spyder to a newer version?

Would anybody be able to help me out?

Answer (score 1):

A small update: I have fully removed my python/anaconda enviroment and reinstalled it from a blank state. This gave me the solution. An 4 hour-ish struggle has come to an end. I do am curious what steps I could have taken in this ordeal without not having to fully reinstall Anaconda.